# Trying to make twoord.plot interactive

Tags: r, function, plot, plotrix

I have a plot that I created using thet `twoord` function. I am trying to make it an interactive graph so that I can hover around a point with my mouse and see what the x,y coordinates are for that plot.

I can't figure out how to do this with the `twoord.plot` function. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: what programming language are you using or is this not a programming language-related question?  Basically... what are you using?

Comment: This programming question is for R

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: My apologies, I was misreading the R command for identify. FYI, just place this code: identify(x, y, labels=row.names(mydata))  after the plot command and you are able to select points accordingly.

Comment: you should post this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, I was misreading the R command for identify. FYI, just place this code: identify(x, y, labels=row.names(mydata)) after the plot command and you are able to select points accordingly.